# SignalR with Angular 4

Tags: angular, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to connect to a SignalR Hub and retrieve data by using Angular 4.
I would appreciate if you could provide me with a sample as how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular2-and-signalr-part-1/ or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-signalr-angular2-and-typescript-real-time-clock/ . SO wont do your research job

Comment: I tried it by using  c-sharpcorner.com,but I received an error called "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hubConnection' of undefined"

Comment: @ArunaNamal Are you sure that this  hubconnection undefined error still persists? Because this will occur if server is not ready or the url we configure in client is incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here I would like to provide you with SignlR service which i have used in my project. Hope this helps you understand.

```
import { CommonService } from './commonService';
import { AuthSettings } from '../authSettings';
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

declare const $: any;
@Injectable()
export class SignalRService {
  private connectionId;
  private authData;
  private signalRConnectionId;
  private proxy: any;
  private connection: any;
  private tryingToReconnect = false;
  public ExpiredBidStatus: EventEmitter<any>;
  public ActivatedBid: EventEmitter<any>;
  public Notification: EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor(private commonSvc: CommonService) {
    this.ActivatedBid = new EventEmitter<any>();
    this.ExpiredBidStatus = new EventEmitter<any>();
    this.Notification = new EventEmitter<any>();
  }

  public initialize(): void {
    this.connection = $.hubConnection(AuthSettings.apiServiceBaseUri);
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('crowneStockHub');
    this.setToken();

    this.proxy.on('broadcastExpiredBidStatus', (bidId) => {
      this.ExpiredBidStatus.emit(bidId);
    });

    this.proxy.on('broadcastActivatedBid', (bid) => {
      console.log('activated bid');
      this.ActivatedBid.emit(bid);
    });

    this.proxy.on('broadcastNotification', (notification) => {
      console.log('notification');
      console.log(notification);
      this.Notification.emit(notification);
    });

    this.proxy.on('broadcastTimeOut', () => {
      this.initialize();
    });

    this.stopConnection();

    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      console.log('Now connected');
      this.connectionId = this.connection.id;
      this.commonSvc.signalRConnectionId = this.connectionId;
    }).fail((error: any) => {
      console.log('Could not connect ' + error);

    });

    this.connection.reconnecting(() => {
      this.tryingToReconnect = true;
    });

    this.connection.reconnected(() => {
      this.tryingToReconnect = false;
    });
    this.connection.error((error) => {
      this.initialize();
    });
    this.connection.disconnected(() => {
      if (this.tryingToReconnect) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.initialize();
        }, 5000);

      }
    });

  }

  setToken() {
    this.authData = window.localStorage.getItem('authorizationData');
    if (this.authData) {
      const token = this.authData.token;
      $.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token };
    }
  };

  stopConnection() {
    this.connection.stop();
  };

  getConnection() {
    return this.connectionId;
  };
}
```

Comment: What is CommonService here ? Can you please explain it or provide Common Service code example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jota.Toledo,  [c-sharpcorner.com/article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-signalr-angular2-and-typescript-real-time-clock/) works for me.
In addition to that I have modify OwinStartup as below.

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

app.MapSignalR();
```